# Embedding between Two posets

Tags: order-theory

Suppose $X$ is a finite poset (partially ordered set). 
Then does an embedding $f$ always exist between the finite poset $X$ and the $\Bbb R^3$ (ordinary $3$-d space)?

Comment: In what sense do you mean an embedding? What is the order on $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: (I mean, this is certainly not set theory, I'm just trying to figure out the full meaning of the question so I can try and retag it properly.)

Comment: @Asaf: I think that [tag:order-theory] will do to be getting on with.

Comment: @Brian: It seems to me rather about simplicial complexes to me. Where the embedding might be the nodes connected with edges. I don't know, though, which is why I asked.

Comment: @Asaf: I’m inclined to take it at face value, unless the OP indicates otherwise, and to assume that we’re talking about the natural product partial order on $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: @Asaf: See the addition to my previous comment. It’s an interesting question (on that interpretation).

Comment: @Brian: I'm not sure what is the natural product here; but I guess it means comparing coordinate-wise. In that case, $\mathcal P(\{0,1,2,3\})$ ordered by $\subseteq$ should be a good example.

Comment: @Asaf: there is a categorical product, and it is given by coordinatewise comparison as one might expect.

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, coordinatewise comparison is the normal product order. I suspect that some finite power set order isn’t embeddable, but actually proving it may be a bit messy. I’ve not played enough yet to have a good feel for it.

Comment: @user220927: if you mean the product partial order, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension for some details.

Comment: @Qiaochu: If anything, I'd expect the lexicographic product to be the one used, since it preserves good properties like being well-founded, linearly ordered and so on.

Comment: @Asaf: But you can’t (isomorphically) embed an arbitrary finite partial order in a linear order.

Comment: @Brian: I am well aware of that, c'mon. Which is why my first comment was to ask in what way the space is ordered.

Comment: @Asaf: I was responding to your *expect* comment to Qiaochu, which I (mis?)read as referring to expectation here rather than in general.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\langle P,\le\rangle$ be a partial order in $\Bbb R^3$. For $k=1,2,3$ let $\le_k$ be the partial order on $P$ induced by the natural order on the $k$-th coordinate. Clearly $\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle\le\langle y_1,y_2,y_3\rangle$ iff $x_k\le y_k$ for $k=1,2,3$, so $\le$ is the intersection of the orders $\le_k$ ($k=1,2,3$). Thus, the dimension of $P$ is at most $3$. It follows that the $8$-element partial order of dimension $4$ illustrated in the Wikipedia article on [order dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_dimension) cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: How surprising that the dimension of $\Bbb R^3$ is $3$ in this context as well. (Not.)