# Existence of a Embedding between two Posets

Tags: order-theory

> Prove that not every finite Partially ordered set can be embedded into $\Bbb R^3$ (ordinary $3$D space) with the partial ordering as follows.
>   $(x_1,y_1,z_1)\preceq(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ if and only if $(x_1\ge x_2)\land(y_1\ge y_2)\land(z_1\le z_2)$

I don't know how to show that there does not exist such a embedding and how to construct such a set X.

Comment: The partial order $\preceq$ is a very minor modification of the usual product partial order on $\Bbb R^3$. You should be easily able to modify my answer to [your previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183478/embedding-between-two-posets) to answer this one.

Comment: Just because the previous question wasn't [set-theory] doesn't mean that this one is [elementary-set-theory], though.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry but this one is the problem from discrete mathematics and I didn't even heard about the order dimension and order theory. All I know is just partial order and linear order. .. The book does not introduce such kind of complicated concepts